Trying to cross-compile the driver during kernel compilation; the driver does not compile
I'm trying to learn Linux and compile the kernel with my simple driver.
Unfortunately, I do not see the driver in the logs and the compiled file is not created.
drivers/misc/answer.c:
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
 
/* Module Init function */
static int __init hello_world_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "This is the Simple Module\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "Kernel Module Inserted Successfully...\n");
    return 0;
}
/* Module Exit function */
static void __exit hello_world_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Kernel Module Removed Successfully...\n");
}
 
module_init(hello_world_init);
module_exit(hello_world_exit);
 
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple hello world driver");
MODULE_VERSION("2:1.0");

drivers/misc/Makefile:
...
odj-$(CONFIG_ANSWER)            += answer.o
...

drivers/misc/Kconfig:
...
config ANSWER
        tristate "Add the answer"
        help
                my module
...

.config
...
# Misc devices
CONFIG_ANSWER=y
...

Compile the kernel
$ sudo make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- Image modules dtbs

I don't see my file in the command output.
Also the driver is not compiled. I added the driver to the menu; shown in .config.
I simplified the driver as much as possible. If there were errors in it, would it appear in the output?
I also tried to change the permissions.
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   955 Jul 31 17:52 answer.c


What am I doing wrong?

You haven’t provided any evidences that your file wasn’t compiled. But I believe that you compile something, that doesn’t have your file. Are you trying to compile in-tree or out-of-tree module? If the second one, you should understand the meaning of y in the Kconfig.

ok let's start over)
the file answer.o should be created, correct?
I checked it, and it was not created
' $ ls | grep answer answer.c '
do you mean to change Y to M?

Where did you place your answer.c and where is the Makefile that you are showing?  Simply placing a Makefile and a .c file in a directory does not automatically build the module.

That's weird, I was adding it to the post. anyway, I updated the post.
Yes, I also added it to Kconfig and configured it in the config menu, isn't that enough?

@MarcoBonelli, It's me, who dropped that and I agree that it may be useful information. I amended my changes.

You have a typo in your Makefile.
odj-$(CONFIG_ANSWER)            += answer.o

Should be
obj-$(CONFIG_ANSWER)            += answer.o


Well of course. It couldn't work, your nickname definitely conveys the clarity of your response. thank you.

You are very welcome.  Sometimes all it takes is another set of eyes. Too bad the other guy's were so full of condescension. People come for help and are frustrated already... They shouldn't be spoken to in the manner he did to you. I'm sorry that you had to deal with that. Good luck on your journey!
